# When the new moon will become visible - after how many hours of conjunction

Tags: astronomy, estimation, solar-system, moon

The moon will be totally invisible during Conjunction of moon, sun and earth.
After how many hours of conjunction, moon will be visible from earth.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It's never totally invisible. It becomes very difficult to see. When it becomes *practically* invisible depends on atmospheric conditions, observation method, instrument, ...